# how to use spark to count continuous identical event?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a user action DataFrame, like

```
+-------+-----+------+
|user_id|stamp| event|
+-------+-----+------+
|   usr1|    1|gather|
|   usr1|    2|  kill|
|   usr1|    3|  kill|
|   usr1|    4|  jump|
|   usr1|    5|  kill|
|   usr1|    6|  kill|
|   usr2|    1|  jump|
|   usr2|    2|  jump|
|   usr2|    3|gather|
|   usr2|    4|  jump|
+-------+-----+------+
```

I want to count continuous identical event, get a DataFrame like

```
+----+------+-----------+
|user| event|event_count|
+----+------+-----------+
|usr1|gather|          1|
|usr1|  kill|          2|
|usr1|  jump|          1|
|usr1|  kill|          2|
|usr2|  jump|          2|
|usr2|gather|          1|
|usr2|  jump|          1|
+----+------+-----------+
```

I want to count continuous identical event of a user, not count event of a user, how to do this by Spark?

What's more, event sequence of one user is very very large(max 0.4 million), groupBy method maybe OOM.

tks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is via RDD by :

1. Repartition and group data of a single user
2. Now iterate over it and apply your Own logic to get your required rows
3. Flatmap it to flatten your rdd
4. convert back to DF

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import scala.collection.mutable.Seq;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}

// assuming your initial df is called "userDf" with ["user_id", "stamp","event"]

val pairRdd = userDf.rdd.map(row => (row(0).toString,row))
val groupedRdd = pairRdd.groupByKey();

// your user related data are brought together in an partition 
// now apply your complex logic for each parititon 

val rddOfInteratorOfRow = groupedRdd.map{
      (it) => {

        var sortedlist = it._2.toList.sortBy( x => x.get(1).asInstanceOf[Int])
        var mySeq : Seq[Row] = Seq.empty

        var count=1;
        var prevEvent = sortedlist.apply(0).apply(2).toString;
        sortedlist = sortedlist.drop(1);

        for( row <- sortedlist){

          if(row(2).equals(prevEvent)){
            count=count+1;
          }
          else{
            mySeq = mySeq:+Row(it._1,prevEvent,count);
            count = 1;
            prevEvent = row(2).toString;
          }
        }
        mySeq = mySeq:+Row(it._1,prevEvent,count);

        mySeq.toIterator
      }
    }

val flattendRdd = rddOfInteratorOfRow.flatMap(x =>x)

val schema = new StructType()
      .add(StructField("user_id", StringType, true))
      .add(StructField("event", StringType, true))
      .add(StructField("count", IntegerType, true))

val finaldf = spark.createDataFrame(flattendRdd,schema)
/*
scala> finaldf.show
+-------+------+-----+
|user_id| event|count|
+-------+------+-----+
|   usr1|gather|    1|
|   usr1|  kill|    2|
|   usr1|  jump|    1|
|   usr1|  kill|    2|
|   usr2|  jump|    2|
|   usr2|gather|    1|
|   usr2|  jump|    1|
+-------+------+-----+
*/
```

This might be the most efficient way, but I am unaware of any DF based shorter and efficient solution out of the box by spark.

Comment: event sequence of one user is very very large(max 0.4 million), maybe OOM at groupByKey.

Comment: Since your question requires a OrderBy records for a particular user_id, it has to be brought to a single partition. How can you maintain order and compute if data is in different partitions. ?